# C:/Python27/ArcGIS10 doesnt exist

Tags: python, installation, arcpy, arcmap, reinstall

I removed Python 2.7 from my Computer because there was a Problem with **arcpy**.
Now I installed the program again. But now I cant connect Python with ArcGis anymore. The path: C:/Python27/ArcGIS10 doesnt exist anymore.
I would be glad if anyone could help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Shot in the dark: try finding a config file or options and resetting the file path

Comment: Look for it in program files or at other location